# Menu impossible to click on in IE

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have some code that creates a list that when hovered on, drops down to reveal a sub menu. the problem is is that it doesn't work in IE. When the link is hovered over in IE, it doesn't drop the menu down but it pushes it over to the right, making it impossible to click on.

This code works perfect in FF and Chrome and the website I got the code from said that it should work in IE.

I'm fairly new at coding as I tend to copy and paste chunks of code and learn little bits so figuring something like this out on my own is way too difficult.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

CSS:

```
#dropmenu,
#dropmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#dropmenu {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}

#dropmenu li {
     width: auto;
}

#dropmenu > li {
    float: left;
    width: auto;    
}
#dropmenu li a {
    display: block;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#dropmenu ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
}
#dropmenu ul li a {
    width: 80px;
}
#dropmenu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

/* Main menu
------------------------------------------*/
#dropmenu {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #;
}
#dropmenu > li > a {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#dropmenu > li:hover > a {
    background: #;
    color: #000;
}

/* Submenu
------------------------------------------*/
#dropmenu ul {
    background: #;
}
#dropmenu ul li a {
    color: #000;
}
#dropmenu ul li:hover a {
    background: #f16b20;
}   
#dropmenu ul li:hover a {
    color: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="dropmenu">
    <li><a href="#">Our Company</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Hellenico</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Genere</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Indulgentia</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Solutions</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Hellenico</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Genere</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Indulgentia</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Service Desk</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Hellenico</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Genere</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Indulgentia</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">resources</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Hellenico</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Genere</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Indulgentia</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Hellenico</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Genere</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Indulgentia</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fUDf8/)

Comment: I've tried on 8 and now I have 10 and it's still the same problem

Comment: I made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bXVmE/) and while it doesn't work perfectly (the `background: #;` doesn't do what you hope it does) it does work the same on IE9 as on Mozilla.

Comment: Probably missing doctype causes IE to switch to Quirks mode?

Comment: I've looked into the doctype situation and I tried a couple but nothing worked, unless I just chose the wrong doctypes? :/

Comment: use `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` and it works on IE 10. don't have any other IE version to check.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` should be enough for the most practical cases. Transitional doctypes are not recommended because they switch modern browsers to Almost Standards mode (aka "Limited Quirks mode") that sometimes causes problems with inline-blocks alignment (at least in Opera).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just done following changes in your css. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dsQeE/1/)**

```
  #dropmenu li {
         width: auto;
         position:relative; /*newly added*/
    }
    #dropmenu ul {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        z-index: 999;
        left:0;  /*newly added*/
        top:20px; /*newly added*/
    }
```

Comment: Yes that's worked! I just had to drop the ul slightly as it was hovering high by a few pixels.
I used `margin-top:10px;`

Comment: You can edit from the top position as per your requirement.

#dropmenu ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
 left:0;
 top:26px; /*you can set the drop down menu position from top*/
}

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Add a `position:relative;` to your `#dropmenu li`, this can do. also try it with a `margin-left: 0;` to your `#dropmenu li ul`</strike>

I did the follow and its working for me:

```
/* added position relative */
#dropmenu li {
    position: relative;
    float: left; 
}
```

And removed `#dropmenu > li`

And added the padding, background and margin-left to #dropmenu ul

```
#dropmenu ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Nope nothing im afraid :(

Comment: It's made the alignment better in chrome and FF but still having the same problem in IE

Comment: This solution deserves a WOMM certification.